# UK Standard Visitor Visa refusal due to funds parking and deception. What are my options?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, proof-provenance-of-funds, deception

I have been recently refused a visit visa to UK. There are couple of reasons, which are quite obvious. I did not provide the authorities some proper proofs which could have supported my application, and in absence of such proofs, they refused to provide me a visit visa.

I am about to begin a new application, but before I do so, I would like to ask you guys some questions to learn how to avoid to repeat the same mistake.

1. I am an international student, studying my Masters degree in Tallinn, Estonia, self funding my studies. I am in my final semester. What documents should I provide which satisfy the UK visa authorities that I won't slip in UK and will come back after the proposed time spent in the UK?
2. I have completely forgotten to mention in the application that I have applied before in 2007 for studies in the UK, and received refusal at that time as well. Do I need some documents to clarify this or should I just mention that in the application the cause of the refusal when asked in the application?
3. My reason to obtain a visit visa is to visit my brother, who is a permanent resident in UK. Though I did present his bank statements and his passport copy, I could not provide an invitation letter from him. What do you suggest in this scenario?
4. If I need to reapply for the same purpose of travel, should I use the same account which I have made for the previous application for UK visa online application?

[image]
[image: Page 2]

Comment: Do they really use Word to make these things?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> 01) I am an international student, studying my Masters degree in
>   Tallinn, Estonia. self funding my studies.I am in my final semester.
>   what documents should i provide which satisfy the Uk visa authorities
>   that i won't slip in uk and will come back after the proposed time
>   spent in the Uk?

They got you on funds parking, it's a very common refusal ground. Please see [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

There is also some interesting background information about this in the site's archives at [What is 'funds parking' in the context of UK visa applications?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62411/what-is-funds-parking-in-the-context-of-uk-visa-applications)

> 02) i have completely forgotten to mention in the application that i
>   have applied before in 2007 for studies in the UK, and received
>   refusal at that time as well. do i need some documents to clarify this
>   or should i just mention that in the application the cause of the
>   refusal where it has been asked in the application?

People who forget to properly record something in their application have a very difficult time going forward. While clerical errors can occur like the omission of a single check mark, yours left an entire section of the form blank and trying to explain it as simply forgetting something isn't going to work very well.

Why? If you previously applied in 2007, it means you were at least 18 at that time and this means the refusal is in your *adult* memory and if your brother is a UK permanent resident you would have extra impetus to be aware of your own history vis-a-vis the UK.  Regardless if you truly forgot or not, from their point of view they would say that it's more likely you forgot about giving your biometrics and/or gambled that a new passport along with an EU class "D" visa would carry your application.

> 03 my reason to obtain visit visa is to meet my brother, who is a
>   permanent resident in UK. though i did present his bank statements and
>   his passport copy, but could not provide an invitation letter from
>   him. what do you suggest in this scenario?

The ECO does not believe you and in the context of the application as a whole there is little benefit by adding an invitation letter from your brother; they would most likely dismiss it as contrived given the tone of the refusal notice.

> 04)if i need to reapply for the same purpose of travel, should i use
>   the same account which i have made for the previous application for UK
>   visa online application?

Yes, you can use the same account. To do this you can click on 'delete application' for your current application, and then click the options to start a new application.  Alternatively you can edit/update your application and submit it again.

Important: Because they got you on [Paragraph 3.6 of Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules), they have the *option*, but not the *obligation*, to [issue a ban](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57715/uk-visit-visa-refusal-deception-and-reapplying-procedure/57737#57737) if you apply again. Explaining away your false representations is not a matter of a blithely telling them you forgot.  And in the best case they will use the *discrepancy method* to refuse again.  The "best practices" advice when there are serious problems is to show your refusal to a [UK solicitor](http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/) who can make representations on your behalf with a fresh application. It will be expensive in your case because they got you on funds parking and false representations.

---

Note: See also [What can I do to lift a 10 year ban for making a mistake in my UK visa application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/64097/what-can-i-do-to-lift-a-10-year-ban-for-making-a-mistake-in-my-uk-visa-applicati)

Note: See also [Deception](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deception)

Note: "*Discrepancy Method*" in this context means to aggressively hyperbolize any sort of deficiency when there is an opportunity to do so. This method can be used for high-risk applicants with perceived or real credibility problems.

Comment: +1 it might be useful to include a link [to this post with a great answer of yours](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/64097/32134) as a reference for 2) ?

Comment: Is it worth the new application pointing out that the incorrect answer to visa refusal was by a matter of months? In fact, by the time of the re-application, the earlier refusal may fall out of the 10-year window.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus an astute call on your part, but I wouldn't tell an ECO that I had trouble reckoning time intervals :). The OP's opener would be to own it, full on straight up. Own it as a judgement failure. And then go from there to mitigators. Any sort of hedging will see the discrepancy method as a result. Or an outright ban. But it's really a qualified solicitor's call, we're just random people on the net :)