# UK Family Visa rejected due to submission of falsified document

Tags: visas, uk, family

I have been told that I may have been banned to enter the UK in March 2016 because I edited the date of my expired bank statement. The Entry Clearance Officer (ECO) inferred that I was deceiving them with a false document. And I didn't apply for family visit visa any more. My newborn baby and wife are both British citizen and my wife has been depressed and sick because of this problem. Is there any way they forgive me and remove the automatic ban?

Comment: Yes - wait ten years. Learn that cheating has permanent consequences in life.

Comment: You should talk to embassy/consulate which has rejected your visa to clarify whether you've got a ban or not.

Comment: *Inferred*? Do you have any reason why your falsification of a supporting document should *not* be considered as deception?

Comment: they refused my first application because the bank statement issued 39 days before my appointment and they told me it was valid only for 20 days. The travel agency which sorted my documents edited it and told me we edit the date and you dont need to wait for a new bank statement.

Comment: Can you please attach a scan of your refusal letter with your personal information blacked out? It is impossible to fully understand your situation here. You state that you have been "told" you `may` be banned, well by whom? Best would be to upload your refusal letter.

Comment: More or less related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73243/uk-family-visitor-visa-refused-on-account-of-having-a-criminal-conviction-howev?rq=1

Comment: Similar questions on this site usually get answers that go something like: "You'll have to hire a good immigration lawyer to have any real chance.  Expect to pay several thousand pounds at minimum."

Comment: Too late for the OP, but may be useful for others: Travel agents have entirely different trade-offs from their clients. The client cancelling the trip because of the bank not being able to supply a statement in time costs them just as much as if the client fails to get the visa because of deception. For an unscrupulous travel agent, the risk is worth taking. For the client, if the deception is detected it may negatively affect visa applications for many years, much worse than having to cancel one trip.

Comment: It is possible that the travel agent has defrauded you, taken your money and not actually made any application.

Comment: @user16259 That would be the best possible situation. Unless the travel agent is very good at forging documents, a refusal letter they wrote is likely to have anomalies that people here might detect. Again, scanning, sanitizing, and posting the refusal letter is the best way forward.