# Second refusal of UK academic visit visa

Tags: visa-refusals, deception

I am from Palestine and I have applied for a business academic visa and got refused due to financial and personal issues. Photo of refusal attached.

I have submitted another application in which I have justified each and every point they have commented on in the first refused application, which I believe convincing.

I have missed to mention that I have submitted an application previously and got rejected. For that reason, the visa got refused again.

Shall I submit a third application, considering that they have mentioned that I am more likely to be refused again? [image]

Comment: The first question that comes to mind is "Why did you not mention the earlier refusal?", immediately followed by "Why did your application get rejected earlier?"

Comment: bank account statement does not show currency, they thought I had 30000 ILS, while my saving account is 30000 USD

Comment: 1 USD = 3.6 ILS

Comment: I have attached every thing needed in the second application, but got rejected to my stupid mistake of not mentioning the first application

Comment: I think the more important of the two questions is "Why did you not mention the earlier refusal?". It is being interpreted as a deliberate omission.

Comment: i have missed that

Comment: is it worthless to go for third application ?

Comment: Regardless of what happens with this application, keep both sets of refusal paperwork. You may be asked about visa refusals from any country on future applications.

Comment: Also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57715/standard-visitor-visa-refusal-deception-v3-6b-and-procedure-for-reapplying

Comment: It appears you are not going to the UK anytime in the near future or even distant future. Applying for the third time is a waste of money. The best you could do is get a qualified immigration attorney. Even then I suspect you would fail because not only are you being refused now based on fraud, you were refused twice based on other criteria from the get go. Your application could be considered tragically and fatally flawed with almost no hope of resuscitation.

Comment: @SheikPaulofOsawatomie As I understand the situation, there was only one refusal for "personal and financial issues". The second application was rejected with the notice scanned in the question, and the OP is asking whether it is worth filing a third application.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan That is correct. But this second refusal was not only for fraud but for other reasons also. So basically he has two refusal for other reasons, and one for fraud although one fraud + other  was within one submission. He's pretty much doomed either way.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan yes, I think you are correct; regardless of if it's the first or second refusal, a V 3.6 (b) refusal is showstopper. Full on and full stop. End of line, done and dusted.

Comment: @GayotFow Has the asker been banned for ten years? It's not mentioned in the question or in the section of the refusal notice.

Comment: @DavidRicherby you're right, they wait for the NEXT application to install the ban because P320 says the deception must be in a *previous*  application. So the linked question is his answer. The OP is in for a ban no two ways about it (unless they avoid applying). I thought long about putting an answer in, but there's so much overlap it seemed pointless. Based on the ECO's comments vis-a-vis the form, the OP deliberately clicked "None" to advance to the next screen. And did it TWICE on the next screen! Done and dusted full stop.

Comment: it was just a mistake, I have attached the refusal paper to the application. my mistake is I forgot to mention that in the application, that's it !