# Can I appeal a UK refusal and 10-year ban?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

[image]I applied for short stay visa to study in the UK. I was refused and received a 10-year ban. It was said that the employment letter I presented was classified as "not a genuine employment letter", and my name was put on the Black List.

Now, I'm preparing all the documents that will prove my defense, but I do not know to whom I should complain.

What does this mean:

> Any future UK visa applications you make will be considered on their individual merits; however, you are likely to be refused unless the circumstances Of your application change.

Comment: Did you submit fraudulent documents the first time?

Comment: Can you upload a scan of your refusal letter, with personal information blacked out? That might make it easier for us to understand what happened. But if you really did get banned, you're probably going to need assistance from a lawyer specialised in this.

Comment: To answer your question, the sentence you quoted means that all applications are considered fresh applications - ie, just because you were refused before does not mean you will automatically be refused again (especially if there is a significant change in your circumstances); however as you were banned there is a higher chance of your application being rejected - again, unless there is a compelling change in your circumstances.

Comment: Are we to assume that the employment letter was in fact genuine?  If it wasn't then you're in a bad position indeed. If it was, then we can't offer any decent advice without knowing *why* they concluded it wasn't genuine.  Did the refusal disclose the reasoning?  They normally do.  Please add the full text of the refusal to your question.

Comment: thank you very much for your replies, it was not fraudulent documents. it is translated wrong freelancer not employment and they back to the head university not the branch of when I worked. now I have all proved documents but I do not know how to complain? if I apply and change the type of visa do they still reject?

Comment: What is there to complain about? The document was incorrectly translated, and you are required to present accurately translated documents - the document was then presented as something it was not, so the determination that it is not genuine is correct.  Do you mean "appeal" rather than complain?

Comment: Relsted https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57715/standard-visitor-visa-refusal-deception-v3-6b-and-procedure-for-reapplying

Comment: Apply again explaining the translation error and that they had asked the wrong people whether you worked there- sure, sounds valid. Doing this whilst applying for a different type of visa- woah, alarm bells sounding, you're trying to get in the UK via any means possible?

Comment: yes I mean appeal. the reasons why he want to apply again to let them know that he is not cheating in case he will not be able to appeal even if he does not get the visa.

Comment: thank you very much for all your comments. please, what dose mean unless change circumstance ??

Answer (score 6):

The letter you have attached doesn't indicate that you have received a ban, only that future rejected applications may result in one.

Emphasis mine:

> You should note that because **this application has been refused under paragraph *V3.6* of the Immigration Rules**, any future applications may also be refused under paragraph V3.7.
>   **A refusal under paragraph *V3.7* attracts an automatic entry ban period of up to 10 years**.

Your application was refused under V3.6. Future refusals may fall under V3.7, and those would attract the ban.

In particular if you do choose to submit a new application you should ensure that you not only have all of the required documentation in order, but also address the issues raised in the first refusal or you will receive an automatic ban

Comment: If he doesn't address the deception in his next application, his application will be refused under 3.7. That will mean an AUTOMATIC entry ban.

Comment: I don't think that makes anything that I have said wrong, but I'll edit to clarify

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation. I really appreciate that.